# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in angular 5

Tags: angular

Hi I am having an angular 5 application that talks to a Rest backend written using spring boot. In my angular 5 application I have a service class that is calling a rest resource. However I can see the rest api calls are not reaching my spring boot application as i put a debug and it doesnt hit there.

MessageHistoryComponent

```
    export class MessageHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
        private accountService:AccountsService, private campaignsService: CampaignsService,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private flightsService: FlightsService) {

      }
      ngOnInit() {

    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
          range: [ [moment(),moment()], Validators.required],
          cdrStatus: [''],
          msisdn:[''],
          campaign: [''],
          inventory: [],
          flight: []
         }
        );

 this.rangeControl.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (value) => {
        this.campaignsService.getCampaignsWithinRange(
          { 
            accountId : this.currentUserAccount? this.currentUserAccount.id: null,
            campaignStatus: this.campaignStatusIds
          }
        );
      }
     );
    }
    }
```

CampaignService

```
   @Injectable()
    export class CampaignsService {
      private statuses$: Observable<CampaignStatus[]>;
      private types$: Observable<CampaignType[]>;
      config: AppConfig = this.configService.config;

      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private configService: ConfigService
      ) {}

     getCampaignsWithinRange(params: { [param: string]: string | string[] }){
        console.log(params);
        return this.http.get<CampaignUnpaginated[]>(
          `${this.config.api}/campaigns/message-history/unpaginated`,
          {
            params: omitEmptyValues(params)
          }
        );
      }

    }
```

so basically we are listening to value changes on a form control named rangeControl and then calling the getCampaignsWithinRange of CampaignService class. However it is not issueing an http get request to my end point "campaigns/message-history/unpaginated" 
when I print the     console.log(params) within the getCampaignsWithinRange it displays as follows ( taken from vss code debug console)

```
Object {accountId: "b2e9d8bd-f12f-476e-af46-993f9c344768", campaignStatus: Array(3)}
campaigns.service.ts:42
accountId:"b2e9d8bd-f12f-476e-af46-993f9c344768"
campaignStatus:Array(3) ["378f982e-d9e3-466e-b08e-291510028002", "357632f0-1afd-4af2-a8f2-3b964884bfb3", "2f02e5f0-2d56-4583-a9db-f962becbd5f9"]
length:3
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:"378f982e-d9e3-466e-b08e-291510028002"
1:"357632f0-1afd-4af2-a8f2-3b964884bfb3"
2:"2f02e5f0-2d56-4583-a9db-f962becbd5f9"
```

also when i do an Debug: evalute

```
this.http.get<CampaignUnpaginated[]>(
      `${this.config.api}/campaigns/message-history/unpaginated`,
      {
        params: omitEmptyValues(params)
      }
    )
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
```

any idea what am i doing wrong here 
thank you

Comment: There is a lot of code here to look through. I suggest you look at the error message as it will likely identify the file and line number where your mistake is. If it's still not clear you should make a stackblitz or similar minimal example

Answer (score 0):

```
this.rangeControl.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (value) => {
        this.campaignsService.getCampaignsWithinRange(
          { 
            accountId : this.currentUserAccount? this.currentUserAccount.id: null,
            campaignStatus: this.campaignStatusIds
          }
        );
      }
     );
    }
```

i was not calling the subscribe method on getCampaignsWithinRange as it returns the observable.